# Fetching Data from MongoDB Collection with Paging in Global Sorted Order

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, sorting

I am working on a project where I have a MongoDB collection named `words`, containing various words. My goal is to fetch these words in a paginated manner while **maintaining a lexicographically sorted order globally**.

I am currently using the following query to achieve pagination, but the sorting seems to be applied only within each page, and subsequent pages might not maintain the correct lexicographical order:

```js
db.words.find({})
  .sort({ word: 1 }) // Sorting words in ascending order
  .skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
  .limit(pageSize);
```

In this scenario, the sorting is not considering the entire collection, leading to potential inconsistencies in the lexicographical order as I paginate through the data.

One non-scalable approach would be to fetch the whole collection, sort it locally, and then return the requested page data. While I am considering this as a temporary solution, I am looking for more scalable alternatives.

I would like to know if there is a recommended approach to modify this query or if there are alternative strategies to ensure that the lexicographical sorting is maintained globally across all pages. Additionally, since the `word` field is not guaranteed to be unique, I'm looking for a solution that considers this scenario.

Any insights or examples on how to implement lexicographically sorted paging for a non-unique field like `word` would be greatly appreciated.
Furthermore, I intend to implement similar lexicographically sorted paging for other fields like `createdAt`. Any guidance or examples on how to extend this approach to other fields would be extremely helpful as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine, you just need to add an equality breaker to your `sort`, the easiest is to use the `_id` field.

```
db.words.find({})
  .sort({ word: 1, _id: 1 }) // Sorting words in ascending order, if words are equal sort by _id
  .skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
  .limit(pageSize);
```

The `_id` field is unique so this will guarantee stability.

Comment: But it will only sort the fetched elements, right? But I want to sort element considering the whole collection.

Comment: I'm not sure what a "fetched element" is, but it just adds a secondary sort field as a tie breaker to make sure the results are stable (in the same order all the time).

Comment: fetched elements are the docs that the above query finds and performs the sorting on.

Comment: If you want to sort the whole collection then your query needs to match the whole collection.